# Différence between installing geoip as a PHP module VS as an apache2 module

Tags: php, apache2, geoip, maxmind

If [apache module](http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/mod_geoip2/) is installed, you get country code with :

```
$_SERVER['GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE']
```

With the [PHP module/library](http://php.net/manual/fr/ref.geoip.php), you use :

```
geoip_country_code_by_name($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])
```

What is the difference (performance etc...) between these 2 solutions ?
Which one is the best ? For which need ?

I think apache module loaded extention in memory for every request, which could be bad for performances. (Or you have to set rules with `GeoIPEnable Off/On` but this is not always easy...)
So If you need geoip on some pages only, is it better for performance to use PHP module ?

Answer (score 2):

They're roughly equivalent in performance. We were also curious, so we did some testing both on Digital Ocean VMs and locally with vagrant. The results were the same: Using the Apache Extension, PHP Extension, or PHP Library all delivered fantastic results. No real hit vs not doing GeoIP at all.

You can disable GeoIP within Apache on a directory or file basis using [.htaccess](http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/mod_geoip2/), so if you would like to disable it for some areas you're free to do so there as well.

We've blogged about our tests, with details on how to reproduce: [GeoIP Performance Examined](https://wonderproxy.com/blog/performance-of-geoip-apache-extension-vs-php/)